# Trying to add index column to csv file

Tags: python, csv

I was trying to add index column to csv file. I can't use pandas as my file size is too big and with panads it cannot read the whole data.

I tried doing this way;

```
with open('test.csv') as infile, open('sample_.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    for idx, line in enumerate(infile):
        outfile.write(f'{idx}   {line}')
```

This does gives me a column however, the index column gets merged with already existing first column.

[image: check this image here]

Comment: You need to add your separator after `idx`, probably a comma.

Answer (score 0):

CSV stands for comma-separated values. you are writing your lines as if they were tab-separated, which is possible but then it needs to be specified in the "open" function call.
try this:

```
outfile.write(f'{idx},{line}')
```

Comment: worked, thank you!